# Достать из строки числа, включая пробелы

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть текстовый документ со строками. Строки содержат:

```
Ivanov Ivan Ivanovich 31 12 1987
Vasya 15 5 2013
```

Имена могут быть с пробелами. Достаю их с помощью:

```
name = line.replaceAll("\\d", "").trim();
```

Вопрос. Как достать строку с числами, включая пробелы между ними?

```
birthday = line.replaceAll("\\w", ""); //возвращает пустую строку
```

Необходимо разбить строку, считываемую из файла на две строки. Первая содержит имя, вторая дату рождения.

Comment: Files.readAllLines()

Comment: @Maxim пояните свой комментарий пожалуйста, я так понимаю, он прочтет все строки из файла, но как он относится к вопросы ТС?

Comment: А не проще ли будет использовать `line.split(" ")`?

Comment: Нужно удалить все символы, которые не пробелы и не цифры (не силён в регэкспах, наверное, это будет шаблон "[^\s\d]"), а затем Trim.

Comment: @Serodv имя может содержать пробелы. Например, Ivanov Ivan Ivanovich 31 12 1987

Comment: Ну тогда поледние три элемента полученного массива - цифры, а всё что до них - фио

Comment: @Serodv ну как-то "говнокод" получается, по-моему))

Comment: с точки зрения постановки задачи может и да, только впоследствии может понадобиться например только день и или месяц

Comment: @Akina спасибо, Ваш вариант - то, что нужно)

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос, пожалуйста, что должно получиться

Comment: Какой-то умник поставил минус на нормальном решении))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
birthday = line.replaceAll("[^\\s\\d]", "").trim();
```

Или так:

```
name = line.replaceAll("\\d", "").trim();
birthday = line.replace(name, "").trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
    public class SpacesHelp {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String source =
                "Ivanov Ivan Ivanovich 31 12 1987\n" +
                    "Vasya 15 5 2013";
            String[] lines = source.split("\n");
            for (String line : lines) {
                String result = line.replaceAll("(\\w+\\s)?(\\w+\\s)?(\\w+\\s)?(\\d+\\s\\d+\\s\\d+)", "$4");
                System.out.println(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Уже был предложен в комментариях вариант проще, который подошел. Добавил его как ответ.

Comment: Почему такое сложное регулярное выражение?

Comment: А чего в нем сложного? Просто группы максимум может быть 4.